# Openshift routes vs external load balancer

Tags: openshift, load-balancing

I am well aware of [Openshift Routes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#available-router-plug-ins) which supports HAproxy by default, however in what scenarios do we need to use [external load balancer](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html), when routes also provides load balancing.

Also when External load balancer is used, still the internal routes objects are generated, which one takes the preference in that case?

Comment: Best use case for LoadBalancer services is when you need direct TCP access to a pod. HAProxy routes only allow HTTP(S) traffic

Comment: Thanks @WillGordon, I'll accept if you post this as answer, though can you please answer 2nd question- when External load balancer is used, still the internal routes objects are generated, which one takes the preference in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default routing with the OpenShift Software Defined Network plugin (https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/networking/sdn.html) typically looks something like this

```
Internet -> Router -> Service -> Pod
```

This is using the HAProxy router. The HAProxy router "is limited to HTTP/HTTPS(SNI)/TLS(SNI) [traffic], which covers web applications." (https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_router.html)

---

If you need more control over your application ingress, or if you need direct TCP access, this is where a LoadBalancer Service is beneficial (https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html#automatically-assign-create-lb). The workflow now looks like

```
Internet -> Load Balancer -> Service -> Pod
```

This bypasses the route entirely. The load balancer will have its own URL/IP address, separate from the HAProxy router instance. So you should never have a concern of *where* the traffic is coming from. You'll either configure your applications to use the Load Balancer *or* the HAProxy router.

Comment: With load balancer setup as well, openshift require to have the service exposed as a route. What does that mean ? Seems with load balancer as well routes are getting generated  https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html#expose-lb-svc

Comment: To be honest, on 3.11 clusters, I haven't needed to ever create a route first. Have you tried _not_ creating the route to see if it works?

Comment: I was going through the docs to understand the difference, will try load balancer without routes then.